# ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [PUT] "/") when updating user password

Tags: reactjs, ruby-on-rails, ruby, axios, devise-recoverable

1. Hey, guys am stack with updating user password with react front end and devise, plus axios which am using to post that on an api.
2. i have not changed anything from devise but when i hit the api the password is updated and i can use it for login but when i look at the terminal their is an error of ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [PUT] "/")
3. any help is highly appreciated

   ```
         const onFinish = (values) => {
            setLoading(true);
            const session = { "user": { ...values, reset_password_token: params.get("reset_password_token") } }
            const path = "/users/password"
            setAxiosHeaders();
            axios.put(path, session)
                .then((response) => {
                    console.log(response.data)
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    console.log(error);
                })
        }
   ```

- 

1. when i hit the *api* it looks like it is being twice as it throws the same error.
2. I have tried PATCH method also the same story.

- 

Comment: when is that `onFinish` function executed? is there a form being submitted for example?

Comment: when submitting the form

Answer (score 1):

Javascript requests *(xhr / fetch)* redirect with the same http method as original request. You're sending a *PUT* request and your controller redirects to the root url `/`, request to the redirected url is issued with a *PUT* method.

Use status `:see_other` (aka `303`) to redirect with a *GET* method:

```rb
redirect_to root_path, status: :see_other
```

---

You can set these options:

```rb
Devise.setup do |config|
  config.responder.error_status = :unprocessable_entity
  config.responder.redirect_status = :see_other
end
```

But it's probably best to set it up for a json response to begin with instead of html.

*https://github.com/waiting-for-dev/devise-jwt/wiki/Configuring-devise-for-APIs*

Comment: where can i put this redirect because i do not have devise controllers

Comment: it throws out this error undefined method `responder' for Devise:Module (NoMethodError)

Comment: i think the problem problem might be o how am handling the response or put request with axios. because the password is updated and it throws the error in the console

Comment: @mutebigodfrey you have to update devise and responders to use these options. set axios `Accept` and `Content-Type` headers to `application/json`, if that doesn't change the response, try adding `respond_to :html, :json` to ApplicationController. https://github.com/heartcombo/devise#hotwireturbo

Comment: respond_to :html, :json  i have already got this in my application controller but still its not getting right